# Automapper map custom collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, automapper

Hi im having difficulties mapping a custom pagedlist collection i have created.

I have a pagedList interface like this:

```
public interface IPagedList<T> : IList<T>
```

And the implementation:

```
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
```

Mapping config:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, DestinationViewModel>()
  .ForMember(f => f.Score, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.anotherProperty));
```

I try to map a collection in my controller action like this:

```
var users = userService.GetPagedUsers(page, size, sort, direction);
var model = Mapper.Map<IPagedList<User>, IPagedList<DestinationViewModel>>(users);
```

Firstly, is it even possible to do this? I have had a scout around on stack and havent found a definitive answer. I have had no luck so far i have only received InvalidCastOperations cannot map generic collection of User to pagedlist of DestinationViewModel, which were thrown by automapper. Using a different list type like IList when mapping to the model works, but I need to use the IPagedList interface for all the paging stuff it has. Any help would be greatly appreciated, been pulling my hair out too long on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding an answer after more research, which is no, automapper doesnt support my scenario out out of the box. The two options from here are: To a custom IObjectMapper, using the existing Array/EnumerableMappers as a guide, or write a custom TypeConverter.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I believe there is a solution to this question.

Mapping config:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, DestinationViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PagedList<User>, PagedList<DestinationViewModel>>()
      .AfterMap((s, d) => Mapper.Map<List<User>, List<DestinationViewModel>>(s, d));
```

Then in service/controller:

```
var users = userService.GetPagedUsers(page, size, sort, direction);
var model = Mapper.Map<PagedList<User>, PagedList<DestinationViewModel>>(users);
```

I have not tried using the interface (IPagedList), only implementation (PagedList).

Answer (score 0):

For those who have faced the problem recently, you can achieve the general mapping using custom converters. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Open-Generics.html):

> AutoMapper also supports open generic type converters with any number of generic arguments:
>
> ```cs
> var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
>   cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Source<>), typeof(Destination<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(Converter<,>)));
> ```
>
> The closed type from `Source` will be the first generic argument, and the closed type of `Destination` will be the second argument to close `Converter<,>`.

So the custom type converter would be:

```cs
private class Converter<TSource, TDestination>
    : ITypeConverter<PagedList<TSource>, PagedList<TDestination>>
{
    public PagedList<TDestination> Convert(
        PagedList<TSource> source,
        PagedList<TDestination> destination,
        ResolutionContext context) =>
        new PagedList<TDestination>(
            context.Mapper.Map<List<TSource>, List<TDestination>>(source));
        /* Additional settings comes here. */
}
```

And then register it:

```cs
this.CreateMap(typeof(PagedList<>), typeof(PagedList<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(Converter<,>));
```